# How Do I Setup Multiple Document Roots/Websites with XAMPP?

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I'm using XAMPP 1.8.3-2 on Windows 7 Ultimate x64; fresh installation, with no changes to any of the configuration files.

I'm using XAMPP so I can test the development of my web projects, without having to upload each and every time, as I'm currently doing.

The current document root is `D:/XAMPP/htdocs`.

### Introduction

I have two websites which are hosted by two different web hosts. I use PHP includes for both websites, to generate the structure of the webpages (thus allowing for easier maintenance and editing in the future).

For example, to insert the `<head>` section, containing meta, stylesheets and scripts for **website A**, I use:

```
<?php include("/home/user236/public_html/a/p/head.php") ?>
```

And to do the same for **website B**, I use:

```
<?php include("/home/user792/public_html/s/p/head.htm") ?>
```

### My Situation

Since the two websites are under different hosts, with different usernames, how would I go about altering the configuration of XAMPP to allow me to work with both websites, with just the single XAMPP installation?

To me, this sounds like I'd need to use both document roots, but how can one accomplish this, because both `/home/user236/public_html/` and `/home/user792/public_html/` mean nothing to XAMPP, away from the production servers. For instance, `/home/user236/public_html/a/p/head.php` will work on my server, but it won't work in XAMPP.

This makes me think that I'd have to change all the include paths when working in XAMPP, and then change them again for uploading to the servers; not good with two websites that easily have hundreds, if not thousands of webpages. That pretty much defeats the purpose of me using XAMPP.

Perhaps there's something I'm missing (hopefully)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try search  “Apache Virtual Host”.